# after enabling backend repeater, is installing UltraVNC repeater is essential, or will it work without it?

Tags: graphite, statsd

my /opt/graphite/statsd/local.js

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "127.0.0.1"
, port: 8125
, backends: [ "./backends/graphite", "./backends/repeater" ]
, repeater: [ { host: '10.1.2.16', port: 8125 } ]
, graphite: { legacyNamespace: false,  globalPrefix: "site",  prefixCounter: "testing_server_1" 
, flushInterval: 600 
}
```

i was able to send data to statsd running other machine, but i had to install UltraVNC  repater for that, is there is another way without installing VNC repeater?

Comment: Can you answer your question now? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, installing UltraVNC repeater is `not required`.

please set up a private network interface on both instances.

each statsd instance will communicate with other using `UDP` protocol.

check [see example statsd config file](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/exampleConfig.js) for more info.

You try this up by setting up two different machines using `vagrant`.